# CreateProcess with CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE & keep the console window open

Tags: c++, windows, createprocess

I have a working command-line application that uses the Windows API to create a child process in a new console window. I am using the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag but I need a way to keep that newly opened window from closing when the new process exits.

Here's the existing code:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
LPCTSTR lpAppName = "\\\\fs\\storage\\QA\\Mason\\psexec\\PSExec.exe";

string lpstr = "\\\\fs\\storage\\QA\\Mason\\psexec\\PSExec.exe \\\\" + target + " /accepteula -u user -p pass -s -realtime \\\\fs\\storage\\QA\\Mason\\psexec\\RI.bat";
LPTSTR lpCmd = CA2T(lpstr.c_str());

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi; // This structure has process id
DWORD exitCode = 9999; // Process exit code

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

// Start the child process. 
if (!CreateProcess(lpAppName,   // cmd.exe for running batch scripts
    lpCmd,        // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,              // New Console Window creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    )
{
    cout << "CreateProcess failed: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    getchar();
    return -1;
}

// Wait until child process exits.
cout << "Waiting Installation processes to complete on " << target << endl;
DWORD result = WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

// Get Exit Code
if (!GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &exitCode)) {
    cout << "GetErrorCodeProcess failed: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    return -1;
}

// Close process and thread handles. 
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

How can I make the new console window remain open?

Comment: Add `& pause` to the end of the command.

Comment: What sort of process (command-line or GUI) is the parent?  That is, do you already have a console window of your own?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos Nope that didnt work. I guess because I'm not launching cmd.exe ?? Im just launching psexec.exe with its commands

Comment: @HarryJohnston Its a command line process to launch another command line process. And yes it already has a window of its own!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular instance the easiest solution is to cheat, i.e.,

```
psexec -s \\target cmd /c "\\server\share\file.bat & pause"
```

You're already launching an instance of `cmd.exe` implicitly, to run the batch file, so this doesn't introduce any significant overhead.

For a more general solution, you would need to launch a proxy application (with `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`) that launches the target application (*without* `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`) and then waits.  For bonus points, the proxy application would be the same as the parent application, just launched with a command-line flag that tells it what to do.

Comment: The cheat solution appears to be working but only if the path to my .bat file is NON-UNC if the path is a UNC path somehow the string gets messed up and the wrong command is sent to psexec.exe. The other solution looks like a better idea but I won't be implementing it as I have decided to just let the window close. Thanks for your help!